Arch, Installed as a dependency of another package
I have electron25 package...i'de like to know what package need it...
pacman -Qi electron25

will return:
[...]
Reason for installation: Installed as a dependency of another package
[...]

How can i find the package that require electron25 ?
Thanks in advance

Try pacman -Qii electron25, look for "required by".

required by: Nobody

How about pactree -r electron25. That should show packages that depend on electron25. Info about pactree is in the wiki page for pacman, section 1.4.1.

@PonJar -Sii should do actually. It's normal that an installed package is no longer depended by any other. pacman -Rs $(pacman -Qdt) can be handy for purging such packages (also see -Qdtt)

@TomYan I assume you mean -Qii and not -Sii. I think a common mistake when removing packages is to use just pacman -R rather than pacman -Rs  or even pacman -Rss  to remove unwanted packages. That helps avoid having installed packages that are no longer depended by any other

@PonJar -Qii shows what installed packages require the argument package. -Sii shows all packages in the repos (cache) that do.

@TomYan Thanks, that’s a new one for me

Thanks to @HolyBlackCat
The package was Installed as a dependency of another package...but now the package that require it is no longer installed...therefore i have uninstalled it!
Thanks to all
